# How to create a table row on selecting a gridview checkbox using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using a gridview with checkboxes and i need to create a table row out of it on checking any of the checkboxes in the gridview. I need help to get the selected row of the gridview using javascript.

GridView Source Code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdCustomer" runat="server" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="3"
        ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Width="640px" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        OnRowDataBound="GrdCustomer_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <input id="selector" onclick="javascript:bindToList(this);selectCustomers();" runat="server" type="checkbox" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <input id="selector" onclick="javascript:SelectDeselectAllCheckboxes(this);selectCustomers(); " runat="server"
                        type="checkbox" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Salutation" HeaderText="Salutation">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Client Name">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Email">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Basic script being called on checkbox check state (only started)

```
 function selectCustomers() {
        alert("Hey I'm over here!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tried it on a gridview but you can select the 'tr' element by using the **parentNode** property of an element in JS. The 'tr' is probably your selected row.

eg.

On the click of check box use the following code,

```
onclick="javascript:selectCustomers(this);"
```

Then in the function,

```
function selectCustomers(chkbox) {
       var desiredparentelement = chkbox.parentNode.parentNode; // Use parent property to get tr
    }
```

Inspect your html element to know how many parents the check box have. Use Mozilla or Chrome tools for inspecting elements.

Comment: Thank You...it's 'parentElement'